# How to get last JSON object from JSONArray for given value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, performance

I have JSONArray like given below

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "abc",
        "isActive": true
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "cde",
        "isActive": false
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "efg",
        "isActive": true
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "firstName": "ghi",
        "isActive": false
    }
]
```

Now I want to get the last object from this array who have value "isActive": true using the most effective and optimized way.

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "firstName": "efg",
    "isActive": true
}
```

UPDATE :

let getLast = items.filter(item => item.isActive === true);

I tried using the solution provided by @brk. But is there any way to get object using without creating a new array.

Answer (score 2):

First `filter` with condition `isActive === true`. This will create a new array , then use `array.length-1` to get the last element

```js
let data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "abc",
    "isActive": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "cde",
    "isActive": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "firstName": "efg",
    "isActive": true
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "firstName": "ghi",
    "isActive": false
  }
]

let getLast = data.filter(item => item.isActive === true);
console.log(getLast[getLast.length - 1])
```

Comment: Is there any way to get an object without creating new array ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
var x=[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "abc",
    "isActive": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "cde",
    "isActive": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "firstName": "efg",
    "isActive": true
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "firstName": "ghi",
    "isActive": false
  }
];

//Try the following line

x.filter(x=>x.isActive).slice(-1).pop()
```

Comment: @brk I have removed `==` Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jsonObject = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "abc",
    "isActive": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "cde",
    "isActive": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "firstName": "efg",
    "isActive": true
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "firstName": "ghi",
    "isActive": false
  }
];

var lastActiveElement = jsonObject.filter( obj => obj.isActive ).pop();

console.log(lastActiveElement);
```

If this is what you are looking for